# Are phone companies liable for condoning and possibly profiting from scam robocalls?

Tags: class-action

Today I received **eight** scam robocalls about my social security number being suspended and only **one** real call. On average, **2/3** all calls in the US are robocalls, many of them scams. This is a [well-known problem](https://www.latimes.com/business/lazarus/la-fi-lazarus-fcc-robocalls-20160729-snap-story.html) that the phone service companies can fix but are unwilling to do so for years. One of the possible reasons may be that the scammers are simultaneously paying customers of the phone companies, paying for the lines they are making the robocalls from.

Besides causing the huge amount of nuisance and the [$10.5 billion financial loss](https://www.securitymagazine.com/articles/90146-phone-scams-cause-americans-to-lose-105-billion-in-2018), robocalls create a security problem to US residents. This is effectively a denial-of-service attack on US infrastructure. The leading advice on avoiding the robocall nuisance is not to answer calls from unknown phone numbers. This effectively means that you cannot call somebody for the first time and expect your call to be answered. A parent may accidentally ignore a call from a school nurse about the kid being sick; the residents of a town such as Paradise, CA may ignore legitimate robocalls from the fire department warning them of danger, etc.

It's well-known that the problem of fake caller IDs and therefore robocalls is not difficult at all to solve technically, and that the only obstacle is the phone companies' unwillingness to interfere. It's also possible that the phone companies' profit from the robocalling customers is a part of their decision.

Thus the question: is it possible to make the phone companies financially liable for the nuisance and the financial loss caused by the robocall scammers? Is something like a class action of cellular service customers v. cellular service companies possible for the amount $10.5B direct loss + lost time and nuisance?